# CSS selectors applied to unrelated elements?

Tags: html, css, html-table, selector

I have a simple page with two tables called `table-a` and `table-b`:

```
<table id="table-a">
    ...
</table>

<table id="table-b">
    ...
</table>
```

and I use the following css to style the appearance of these 2 tables:

```
#table-a {
    width: 100%;
}

#table-a td, tr, th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#table-b {
    width: 100%;
}

#table-b td, tr, th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

The problem is that the `padding-left: 5px;` of `table-b` is also applied to the first table `table-a`.

How does this happen and how do I prevent it from happening?

I really can't figure out how to solve this problem :(...

I thought that by using the following, only those elements are influenced that are "within" `table-b` and not those within `table-a`:

```
#table-b td, tr, th {
    /* ... */
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No need for signatures here on SO (They're not even allowed, see the FAQ for details)

Comment: After a comma: `,` a  new selector is started. So you're selecting all `tr`'s and `th`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second selector `#table-b td, tr, th {...]` selects ALL of the td, tr and ths within the document. You have to prepend the table selector to each one:

```
#table-b td, 
#table-b tr, 
#table-b th {...]
```

Also prepend the `#table-a` to the other selectors as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
...tr, th {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
```

That applies for *all* table rows and headers.

If you want to apply the rules for #table-a, you need to specify the table id before the tr and th:

```
#table-a td, #table-a tr, #table-a th {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `#table-b td, #table-b tr, #table-b th` instead of this `#table-b td, tr, th`. Your version applies the selectors to  #table-b td AND th AND tr